Obtaining the name of the executed chain in the output during runtime
I was going through a tutorial about router chains. Is there a method to fetch the name of the executed chain in the output, such as "math". How can I retrieve the name of the executed chain? Also, is there a way to store the output shown below when the verbosity is set to True, into a variable?
Complete code

